# excel vba resizing print area

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have an excel tool that was made by someone before me. However, when the tool was made, it would output worksheets to a certain size that would fit the printable area in excel 2007. In excel 2010 however, the sizing is off. How can I change the size of the print area in a worksheet without having to change the size of individual cells in each sheet?

Thanks for anyone who can offer their 2 cents.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code that's not working.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  I'd also use the macro recorder.  Turn it on, do the steps needed to get the right fit and it should generate some helpful code.

Comment: I don't have any code. I just have an excel tool that generates new worksheets of information that can be printed. But the size of the newworksheets isn't always suitable. I think I need to change the print size for each sheet with a function and call that function each time a new page is created. Also, the pages are inserted into a new worksheet one by one, so there are multiple printable pages in each sheet. If I can the print area just once, will it make all the pages in that sheet the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the ability to set the print area to a range of cells programatically will get you where you'd like to be:

```
Dim MyPrintArea As Range
Set MyPrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:G15")

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = MyPrintArea
```

Best I could do based upon the ask.

Comment: PrintArea is a string, so your code should be: ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = MyPrintArea.Address or bypass the range and just use the string, like: ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:G15"